# How to write file that is converted to hex to a new file in C

Tags: c, windows

I have an image in `jpeg` format that I converted into a `hex` string using an online tool. I copied that hex string and saved in a text file called `imgHex.txt`. How can I convert the hex value inside imgHex.txt back to its original form (jpeg).

I tried to open imgHex.txt using `"r"` parameter and then open a file `test.jpeg` with the `"wb"` parameter. And the write the contents of imgHex.txt to test.jpeg but with no success.

```
FILE* f;
    FILE* img;
    fopen_s(&f, "C:\\Users\\name\\Documents\\imgHex.txt", "r");
    fopen_s(&img, "C:\\Users\\name\\Documents\\test.jpeg", "wb");

    char b[512];
    while (fgets(b, 512, f) != NULL)
    {
        fputs(b, img);
    }
```

Comment: Do you know the difference between a textual representation of a byte and its actual value?

Comment: I'm sorry I did opened it with "wb"

Comment: @thebusybee Can you explain?

Comment: You can read/write each hex byte with `unsigned val; while(fscanf(f, "%2x", &val) == 1) fputc(val, img)`.

Comment: For example, a binary value of 10100011 can be represented as decimal number with the characters "163". Since this concept seems to be hard for beginners, I'm asking if you know it. Because it is important to realize what you want.

Comment: You will want to retain the return value from `fgets`, you won't always get the full 512 bytes.

Comment: when writing binary repr. dont use fputs, instead use fwrite. fputs adds newline

Comment: Since you do no conversion from the **textual representation in hex** of the data to the actual value, the resulting file is of course no valid JPEG file. Please read the documentation of `fopen()`'s parameters, the mode modifier "b" apparently does not what you think.

Comment: This is impossible to answer (though it is clearly possible to point out mistakes), unless we know the **exact** form of the output file. An example (a **small** jpeg) "converted to hex" (whatever that means) would leap *miles* in the effectiveness of this query.

Comment: @WeatherVane that's a slow but perfectly valid way to do it, as long as the input has nothing but hex digits and white space.  You should write it up as a full answer.

Comment: I'd expect the "online tool" more likely converted the binary JPEG to base64, not hex... Just a thought... Does the "online tool" not provide the reverse facility???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your `imgHex.txt` DOES NOT start with `0x` but rather only consists of the hexadecimal digits, then this is a very simple operation. (If you file does start with `0x`, just skip past the first two bytes of the file).

First, you need to understand that each hexadecimal digit represents 4 bits, i.e. `A = 1010`. This means you need to read two digits at a time so that you have one byte, i.e. `A2 = 10100010`. Once you read each two digit pair, you convert this textual representation of a byte into its actual value. Then you just write that value into your output file. Repeat until you reach EOF for `imgHex.txt`.

(Credits to @Weather Vane for actual code)

```
unsigned val; 
while(fscanf(f, "%2x", &val) == 1) {
    fputc(val, img)
}
```

This code succinctly reads two hexadecimal digits, `"%2x"` from the file handle `f`, and puts the resulting value into `val`. It makes sure that one byte was read from `f`, `fscanf(...) == 1`, in order to make sure no errors occurred. Then it writes the single byte to the file handle `img`, via `fputc(val,img)`.

This will stop since once we reach the end of the `imgHex.txt` file, `fscanf(...)` will not return 1, but rather EOF (*commonly this is -1*, but depends on implementation).